# Equal height children images in responsive Bootstrap 4 columns. How to?

Tags: flexbox, bootstrap-4

Using Bootstrap 4, I'd like to create 3 columns that adjust their width so that padding of each column is consistent and the height of each image is consistent between each column. The goal is for the width and height of each image to increase/decrease as page width changes. Notice, the height of the images and columns should always be synced. I know I can use percentages, but I was hoping there was a flexbox solution. Thanks

Codepen: https://codepen.io/danielgetsthis/pen/qJgyNx

[image: The Problem]

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <a href="#" class="text-center">
        <span>1</span>
        <img src="http://placehold.jp/100x100.png" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <a href="#" class="text-center">
        <span>2</span>
        <img src="http://placehold.jp/200x100.png" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <a href="#" class="text-center">
        <span>3</span>
        <img src="http://placehold.jp/300x100.png" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand the height issue. The columns and images are the same height. To equalize the padding around the images use `col-auto` instead of `col`. This makes the columns shrink to fit the width of their content.

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-auto">
        <a href="#" class="text-center">
          <span>1</span>
          <img src="http://placehold.jp/100x100.png" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-auto">
        <a href="#" class="text-center">
          <span>2</span>
          <img src="http://placehold.jp/200x100.png" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-auto">
        <a href="#" class="text-center">
          <span>3</span>
          <img src="http://placehold.jp/300x100.png" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/XtNGjb765u

Comment: Thank you. "col-auto" is certainly getting there, but the columns don't reduce in width as the screen size gets smaller. When the screen gets smaller, I want to keep having 3 columns and the images should scale down so the columns can also scale down all while maintaining consistent padding.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
  background-color: #eee;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col {
display: flex;
flex: 0;
flex-direction: initial;
}

.col a {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
padding: 10%;
background-color: tomato;
border: 1px solid green;
color: #FFF;
font-size: 26px;
justify-content: center;
}

span{
  display: block;
  text-align:center;
}
```